# Deoplete is not working for Neovim

Tags: linux, vim

So I've installed `neovim` and `deoplete` plugin. I did call `:UpdateRemotePlugins` afterwards. Now, when I write `C/C++` code, its simply doesn't complete. It actually works for things like `patht = ~/Desktop/`, that actually gets the popup menu. Or `Python` code gets completions as well. But as for now I am mostly writing in `C++`, so I would like to make it work. I've got Python 3.6 and 2.7.x. I've did `pip3 install neovim`. I did `call deoplete#enable()` and I've even tried `let g:deoplete#enable_at_startup = 1` (deoplete is working, but not for `C/C++`). I've tried `deoplete_clang`, doesn't complete as well. Where's the problem? This is the output from `:CheckHealth`:

```
    1 
      2 health#deoplete#check
      3 ========================================================================
      4 ## deoplete.nvim
      5   - SUCCESS: has("nvim") was successful
      6   - SUCCESS: has("python3") was successful
      7   - INFO: If you're still having problems, try the following commands:
      8     $ export NVIM_PYTHON_LOG_FILE=/tmp/log
      9     $ export NVIM_PYTHON_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG
     10     $ nvim
     11     $ cat /tmp/log_{PID}
     12     and then create an issue on github
     13 
     14 health#deoplete#check
     15 ========================================================================
     16 ## deoplete.nvim
     17   - SUCCESS: has("nvim") was successful
     18   - SUCCESS: has("python3") was successful
     19   - INFO: If you're still having problems, try the following commands:
     20     $ export NVIM_PYTHON_LOG_FILE=/tmp/log
     21     $ export NVIM_PYTHON_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG
     22     $ nvim
     23     $ cat /tmp/log_{PID}
     24     and then create an issue on github
     25 
     26 health#nvim#check
     27 ========================================================================
     28 ## Configuration
     29   - SUCCESS: no issues found
     30 
     31 ## Performance
     32   - SUCCESS: Build type: RelWithDebInfo
     33 
     34 ## Remote Plugins
     35   - WARNING: "nvim" is not registered.
     36   - WARNING: Out of date
     37     - SUGGESTIONS:
     38       - Run `:UpdateRemotePlugins`
     39 
     40 ## terminal
     41   - INFO: key_backspace (kbs) terminfo entry: key_backspace=\177
     42   - INFO: key_dc (kdch1) terminfo entry: key_dc=\E[3~
     43 
     44 health#provider#check
     45 ========================================================================
     46 ## Clipboard (optional)
     47   - SUCCESS: Clipboard tool found: xsel
     48 
     49 ## Python 2 provider (optional)
     50   - INFO: `g:python_host_prog` is not set.  Searching for python2 in the environment.
    [No Name]                                                                                                                                                                                        1,0-1          Top
  - INFO: Executable: /usr/bin/python2
 52   - INFO: Python2 version: 2.7.13
 53   - INFO: python2-neovim version: 0.1.13
 54   - SUCCESS: Latest python2-neovim is installed: 0.1.13
 55 
 56 ## Python 3 provider (optional)
 57   - INFO: `g:python3_host_prog` is not set.  Searching for python3 in the environment.
 58   - INFO: Executable: /usr/bin/python3
 59   - INFO: Python3 version: 3.6.1
 60   - INFO: python3-neovim version: 0.1.13
 61   - SUCCESS: Latest python3-neovim is installed: 0.1.13
 62 
 63 ## Ruby provider (optional)
 64   - WARNING: `ruby` and `gem` must be in $PATH.
 65     - SUGGESTIONS:
 66       - Install Ruby and verify that `ruby` and `gem` commands work.
```

And this is my `init.vim`:

```
call plug#begin('~/.config/nvim/plugged')
Plug 'Shougo/deoplete.nvim', { 'do': ':UpdateRemotePlugins' }
" call PlugInstall to install new plugins
call plug#end()

call deoplete#enable()

filetype plugin indent on
set number
set nowrap
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set autoindent
syntax on
set noswapfile
set nobackup
```

Is there a way to make it work? I am sure that I have the latest `neovim` and `deoplete` as well. I am using Fedora 26.

Comment: I believe you still need to run `nvim -c':UpdateRemotePlugins'`.